# Anything like a cron on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Ok I have a task i don't want running all the time but i need to periodically check info for the user. I could use a backgroundservice, I'm aware, but is there anything .. I hate to explain it this way, but window.setInterval for android? The App doesn't have a gui It just writes to the sms inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an AlarmManager and run some code when it's triggered. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html